# how to use chart.js in webpack

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack

I'm using chart.js in webpack. when run webpack in terminal it's ok but in console display Error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined"

```
require(['jquery', 'chartjs'], function($, chartjs) {
console.log('aaaaaaaa');

var riceData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
    datasets :
     [
        {
          fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
          strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
          pointColor : "#fff",
          pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
          data : [203000,15600,99000,25100,30500,24700]
        }
     ]
    }

    var rice = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(rice).Line(riceData);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give the variable name `chartjs` to require.js's callback, yet you try to reference chartjs with `Chart` on the second-to-last line. What you would need to do is decide on a naming convention:

```
require(['jquery', 'chartjs'], function($, Chart) {
console.log('aaaaaaaa');

var riceData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
    datasets :
     [
        {
          fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
          strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
          pointColor : "#fff",
          pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
          data : [203000,15600,99000,25100,30500,24700]
        }
     ]
    }

    var rice = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(rice).Line(riceData);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
problem solved. I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by changing `require` to `define` And also you should use the npm package manager.

```
define(['jquery', 'chartjs'], function($, chartjs) {

var riceData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
    datasets :
     [
        {
          fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
          strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
          pointColor : "#fff",
          pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
          data : [203000,15600,99000,25100,30500,24700]
        }
     ]
    }

    var rice = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(rice).Line(riceData);
});
```